# Why does the '+=' operator return undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As I was preparing a function I noticed that it initially returned 'undefined' along with the other information it was supposed to return. Here is [that function](http://jsfiddle.net/wo61yL05/):

```
foo = function(bar) {
    var glorp;
    if(typeof bar == 'undefined'){bar = 'baz'}; // there will be other conditions later
    if('baz' == bar) {
        glorp += 'this, ';
        glorp += 'that, ';
        glorp += 'the other';
        return glorp;
    }
}
```

I'm calling the function like this:

```
$('#glorp').append(foo());
```

The return is this:

> undefinedthis, that, the other

when I expected this:

> this, that, the other

I did quite a bit of digging but I wasn't able to locate anything definitive. I then changed the first of the `glorp` operators to just `=` and the undefined message went away.

Since `glorp` is declared at the opening of the function it should be defined in the `if` statement, and it appears that it is since 'this, ' is successfully returned.

What is being returned 'undefined'?

Comment: You're not initializing the variable. The first thing you do is a `+=` operation, and at that point the value of the variable is `undefined`.

Comment: The initial value of a variable is `undefined`.

Comment: Just change it to "var glorp = "";"

Comment: Time for a coffee break ;)

Comment: I know there is many dupes on this, struggling to find one to close it with.

Comment: I tried to find a dupe @epascarello, but none seemed to be the same question.

Comment: @JayBlanchard out of curiosity what makes you expect that the variable *won't* be `undefined` initially? Like, which statement in your function would give it a value before the first `+=`?

Comment: I didn't really expect it @Pointy - the initial entry of the line (it is a lot more code that I pared down to get to the example) was a typo (+= instead of +). Then I got curious because not only did it return undefined, it returned the first value *at the same time*.

Comment: Well the first `+=` should really be `=`, not `+` - making it `+` will get rid of the "undefined" but it'll also mean that the result will lack the "this, " prefix.

Comment: Yet another typo @Pointy :-/ I *do* need that coffee.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because

```
var glorp;  //<--undefined
console.log(glorp);  //logs undefined

glorp = glorp + "x";  // undefined + "x" -> "undefined" + "x" -> "undefinedx"
console.log(glorp);  //logs "undefinedx"
```

set it to an empty string

```
var glorp = "";
```

Comment: If it is undefined then why does it return the value 'this, ' at the same time that it returns 'undefined'?

Comment: @JayBlanchard: Because you are adding '`this, '`: `glorp += 'this, ';`. That is just a shorthand for `glorp = glorp + 'this, ';` which evaluates to `glorp = undefined + 'this, ';`.

Comment: Ah! Dang, I really do need to get some coffee. Thanks @FelixKling

Answer (score 3):

You need to make `glorp` an empty string at the start

```
var glorp = "";
```

For your output, when you add `undefined + string` it makes `undefined` a string value `"undefined"`. So `"undefined" + "this" = "undefinedthis"`.